# Policy Gradient - Finite Difference Method: $\text{Calculating } \Delta \theta_i$

Tags: reinforcement-learning

In [Policy Gradient Methods for Robotics](http://www.kyb.mpg.de/fileadmin/user_upload/files/publications/attachments/IROS2006-Peters_%5B0%5D.pdf) it says that for the policy parametrization $\theta_i$ the *change* $\Delta \theta_i$ "*is varied by small increments*".

My problem is that I don't understand what *small increments* is supposed to mean.

The algorithm for the *Finite Difference Gradient Estimator* goes as follows:

[image]

But how to generate $\Delta\theta_i$?

Comment: As good an answer as one could expect appears in the following paragraph: "However, the straightforward application to robotics is not without peril as the generation of the $\Delta\theta_j$ **requires proper knowledge on the system,** as badly chosen $\Delta\theta_j$ can destabilize the policy so that the system becomes instable and the gradient estimation process is prone to fail. Problems on robot control often require that each element of the vector $\Delta\theta_j$ can have a different order of magnitude making the generation particularly difficult." (Emphasis added.)

Comment: @whuber Seems legit. So what this means is that I have to perform some kind of grid-search or brute force attack on $\Delta \theta_i$ in order to get proper values? This is just an assignment that I have to do and I am not a "*robotics engineer*" as it is requested in the article ..

Comment: Neither am I a roboticist; my guess is the same as yours. But there are better and worse ways to perform this kind of numerical search. Many are nicely discussed in the *Numerical Recipes* text. I doubt, though, that the algorithm as presented in this table is really what people do, because the result can easily converge to inaccurate estimates. In practice, once you get a sense of how small the $\Delta\theta_j$ need to be, you would only need to generate one or two increments to either side of $\theta_h$ (in each coordinate); you would throw away the (earlier) larger values.